# How to save Element as string in UTF8?

Tags: java, xml-serialization, type-conversion

I convert org.w3c.dom.Element to String in this way:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer));
String result = writer.toString();
```

But when I use it later I get an exception: **io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence** which says about wrong encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it's completely unnecessery. I needed it for serialization nodes and further export them to different formats (xml, html, test). So I found out that it's better to share **org.w3c.dom Documents**. From Document you can get any information you need.